# UITableViewCell horizontal custom swip- to-delete effect

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe

I have a UITableView and would like to have a custom way to delete my cells. When someone swipe on it, the cell would move horizontally on the side and disappear.

Exactly like the multitasking menu on iOS 7 (http://movies.apple.com/media/us/ios/ios7/f34c5445-5a9c-4b3a-9556-8efe89147559/shared_multitasking/shared_multitasking_2x.mp4), but instead of swiping vertically, it would be horizontal.

Does any one knows how to do that? Should I just detect a swipe and change the frame of my cell with a 1 sec animation? Or are there nice subclasses of UITableViewCell you would recommend?

Comment: You will get a sample project "MCSwipeTable" in github check that.

Comment: I tried it and it's really what I'm looking for... except that it doesn't allow any other user interaction on the cell. So the buttons doesn't work anymore. :/

Answer (score 0):

I just threw together a **very basic** example of how to do this and posted it here: https://github.com/NSPostWhenIdle/MMSwipeToDeleteCollection. Don't expect to be able to drag and drop this into your project and have it work, because quite frankly it probably won't.

The basic idea to create something like this starts with a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that adds a gesture to the cell. In my example, I used a swipe gesture because I'm lazy :p and there is more overhead involved in setting up a pan gesture (which you'll want in your end product) because there is conflict between that pan gesture, and the pan gesture in the collection view's scroll view.

From there it's basically smooth sailing. When the gesture recognizer gets called you animate the cell out the top of the screen. If you set this up with a pan gesture, you'll need to configure this to drag the cell, and animate up or down upon completion, but in my swiping example, the cell moves to just out the top (of the 4 inch simulator, I used static values).

Then all that's left to do is some clean up. Once the cell has exited the screen you can safely delete it from your datasource and then from the collection view. (I used notification center do alert the collection view, but you should probably make a protocol) The only issue I had with this was that the cell animated back down while fading out as part of the stock deletion animation. Setting its alpha to 0 after it leaves the screen solves this problem.